# Rails, RSpec, and Capyara/Selenium - how to use the Selenium click_at method to click on exact x,y coords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test clicking on an exact coordinate in an HTML page using RSpec and Selenium in a Rails project. However, the documented Selenium click_at method appears to be unavailable through any of the driver or native method. Does anyone know how to access that method. I am using Rails 3.2.8 and the rspec-rails gem 2.12.0 and the selenium-webdriver gem 2.27.2 and capybar 2.0.1

Right now I'm trying to use this code but it does not click on the proper coordinates:

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to( my_element.native ).move_by( 300, 300 ).click.perform
```

Answer (score 2):

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to( my_element.native, 300, 300 ).click.perform
```